# Cannot set up screen panning in Ubuntu with xRandR which states that it cannot find the modes

Tags: command-line, graphics, monitors, xrandr, display-settings

I am using a Samsung n150 netbook with a 10.1 inch screen and it has a maximum screen resolution of `1024x600`. I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and want to enable screen panning for a larger virtual display; so that the screen seen is a subset of the larger display that can be navigated via the mouse. I believe that the virtual screen size of `1024x800` would suite my purposes, but anything with at least larger y-axis would be suitable.

There is the `Panning-viewport` instructions [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Panning_viewport), which recommends this command:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --rate 60 --mode 800x600 --fb 1280x1024 --panning 1280x1024
```

I have modified the command to suite my situation:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1024x600 --fb 1280x1024 --panning 1280x1024
```

The terminal then prints `xrandr: cannot find mode 1024X600`, and this was the same even with mode 800X600. I tried using `--output VGA1` as well. `xrandr -q` gives (briefly):

```
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+0
1024x600  60.0*+
800x600   60.3
```

I tried `xrandr --newmode 1024x600` as well but no changes happened trying again. I have read the man pages and [wiki randr page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR),[link2](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/randrproto/randrproto.txt),[link3](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#Summing_up),[link4 on using randr](http://x.debian.net/howto/use-xrandr.html) which discuss randr. I cannot understand the command and how to work with it. Even though there is only  an `output` a `rate` a `mode` the `fb` and the `panning` option, I cannot figure out what they are doing and how to set them up for panning on my system.

Is there a simple modification of the terminal line I am using to fix the problems of setting up `panning` or some mode addition include via `--newmode` that should be made?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to generate the new mode

```
gtf 1024 600 60
```

You will get something like:

```
# 1024x600 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 37.32 kHz; pclk: 48.96 MHz
Modeline "1024x600_60.00"  48.96  1024 1064 1168 1312  600 601 604 622  -HSync +Vsync
```

Then present this mode to `xrandr` using `--newmode`

```
 xrandr --newmode "1024x600_60.00"  48.96  1024 1064 1168 1312  600 601 604 622  -HSync +Vsync
```

Then add this mode to LVDS1:

```
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 "1024x600_60.00"
```

And finally you can use this new mode with panning:

```
 xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1024x600_60.00 --fb 1280x1024 --panning 1280x1024
```

Comment: this looks great, im trying to add mode with 1024x800, but im getting errors when trying to add the mode: alex@alex-laptop:~$ xrandr --addmode LVDS1 "1024x800_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  24

what could be the reason?

Comment: You cannot add mode that is bigger than your screen, if you want bigger desktop you can only do this in framebuffer (`--fb` option).

Comment: if my desktop is 1024x600 I cannot have a bigger screen that I can pan? So must I increase the desktop into a bigger panning mode? or is framebuffer some kind of different environment which can be made bigger?

Comment: Everything is in my answer. xrandr mode cannot be bigger than physical size of the screen, but you can use framebuffer to create bigger virtual desktop.

Comment: thanks, could you tell me how to use framebugger to create a bigger virtual desktop?

Comment: I have written this in my answer. It is the `--fb` option.